# Other undelete votes are not properly counted/displayed when a post owner self-undeletes a post

Tags: bug, status-review, deleted-answers, revision-history

Yesterday I cast an undelete vote on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506212/does-visual-studio-code-have-a-builtin-formatter-for-css/72466052#72466052). This undelete vote is shown in the timeline, although it is unattributed so normal users can't tell whether it was an undelete vote by the post owner or by another user:

[image: Timeline showing vote summaries]

The red arrow above indicates my undelete vote, which occurred after the post was deleted by the owner at 1:39:37PM. This lines up with the timing of my undelete vote from my profile, cast at 1:50:01PM:

[image: My Undelete votes page from my profile showing the exact timestamp I cast the vote]

However, in the post timeline page, it does not show my undelete vote on the undelete action recorded when the post owner cast a self-undelete vote to unilaterally undelete it:

[image: Post timeline which shows the post incorrectly undeleted only by Robatron]

While it's true that the post owner's vote was all that was needed to undelete, since it was previously also self-deleted by the post owner alone, I *did* cast an undelete vote, and the system recorded it and is preventing me from casting another, so the timeline *should* show my name on the underlined entry above.

For comparison, when a user casts a delete vote on a post that is later deleted by a moderator or Community, that user's name is shown in the deletion banner and the timeline for the post next to the moderator/Community's name, even though a moderator/Community can always unilaterally delete posts. So this behavior is inconsistent.

**Can this be fixed so that all undelete voters are shown in undelete records listed in a post's Timeline page?**

Also, this appears to be allowing a loophole in the delete vote limit--when a post is deleted by more than the post owner, they can no longer unilaterally undelete it (at least, I think that's how it works). Likewise, once a post has been *un*deleted by more than the post owner, the post owner should no longer be able to unilaterally *delete* it, like the post owner did here (apparently for the *fourth* time...).

Comment: As far as I am aware, there has never been any protection anywhere that prevents post-owner deletion. A mod undeleting a post won't prevent post owner deletion. You are correct about trusted user deletion preventing post owner undeletion.